why is DonatChart not working in Kusto Query
this KQL query works and shows a list
resources
| project type
| summarize count() by type

and I can select charts from the query editor in azure resource graph explorer. However no render command works in the query. Is there a solution or even explenation to it ?


I can select charts from the query editor in azure resource graph explorer. However no render command works in the query. Is there a solution or even explanation to it ?

In resource graph explorer one can only see charts or create charts from chart section, you cannot create them there:

AFAIK, render is not supported in Resource Graph Explorer, to use render you need to use Log Analytics or ADX and to create charts with queries:

Also refer this SO-thread and Microsoft-Document for more information on render as it says render is used in Azure Monitor, ADX, Kusto explorer.

you can add render option to some queries but not to this. I hoped for some explenation why that is there the case. Or maybe some tweak around it. However thanks for the hints

Yes, as this is a limitation in it. Hope you get that
